# How to index a certain line within a powershell object

Tags: powershell, indexing, powershell-2.0

i'm a powershell beginner attempting to webscrape SerialNumbers using a powershell 2.0 script. I am unsure on how to index this list(?) in order to return the SerialNo (2390).
This is the command i have used to locate where the Serial No is stored.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $currentDocument.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName("table") | Select-Object outerText | Format-List
```

Below is the result (--- represents censored data)

```
outerText : Welcome to ---
            Model ---
            MAC Address---
            Serial No.2390
            Firmware Version---
            System Uptime---

            ---


            Basic Settings
            ---
            Network Settings
            ---
            Serial Settings
            ---
            Operating Settings


outerText : Model Name---
            MAC Address---
            Serial No.2390
            Firmware Version---
            System Uptime---
```

It is showing all of the outerText objects, and displaying the information held within the two outerText. have tried to set this as a variable, and tried to index using

```
$test[0]
```

but returns an empty line (no error). is there a way i can index either of these to display the serial number?

Thanks!

edit: have also been playing around with foreach loops, nothing returning so far

Answer (score 0):

When you use Format-List, you convert your type to object[] which loses some of the information you can use to access the variables.

Simple example of such behavior is,

```
$var1 = Get-Process winlogon
$var2 = Get-Process winlogon | Format-List

Write-Output "Handle for var1 -> $($var1.Handles)"
Write-Output "Handle for var2 -> $($var2.Handles)"
```

You would expect the output of both of the var1 and var2 to be the same but, interestingly,

**Output is**

```
Handle for var1 -> 258
Handle for var2 ->
```

and the types changes as well

```
-> $var1.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                  
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                  
True     False    Process                                  System.ComponentModel.Component                                                                                                                                                           

-> $var2.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                  
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                  
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

**Suggestion**

If you want to be able to access the OuterText's serial numbers, I would suggest working without Format-List that you are using in obtaining the `$test` variable

Comment: Thanks heaps for the comment! i initially started out without using a format-list. however the text gets truncated. it only prints the first line of each outertext Object, then cuts off into (...), i will try rework my command to filter a better way

Comment: Output might be truncated but the data should still be there in the `$test` variable